# Doubts over creating and running Laravel migrations

Tags: laravel, migration

I've been reading the documentation, but I still have some doubts about creating migrations. On my project, I ran the `migrate` command to create Laravel's default tables (users, password_resets and migrations). Now I want to, one by one, create the migrations for the remaining tables I have planned on my EER diagram. My doubts are the following:

I can use the `php artisan make:migration create_new_table` to create a new migration and the `--create=tablename` complement is used to create a new table.

- Will `--create=tablename` immediately create an empty the table on the DB?
- Since I already have three tables, should I use `--create=tablename` for every new one?
- After writing all the code, the `migrate` command will run all my migrations. Do I use this command after I've written migrations for all tables? Will running it again overwrite tables I already have on the DB?

It's probably basic stuff, but I want to be sure before going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will --create=tablename immediately create an empty the table on the DB?

No, table will be created when you run `php artisan migrate`. It will create a new migration with "boilerplate" for `tablename`. In this case, this will be added to the migration file:

```
Schema::create('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

> Since I already have three tables, should I use --create=tablename for every new one?

It's really just a helper method for the boilerplate. So if you're creating a new one, it will make it easier.

Personally, I prefer creating migrations with `php artisan make:model -m SomeModel`, which will create the model and a boilerplate migration (because of `-m` option).

For example, if you run `php artisan make:model SomeModel -m`, it will a) create a model named SomeModel b) create a boilerplate migration (called somethinig like `timestamp_create_some_models_table`) with:

```
Schema::create('some_models', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I like it because it's easy to stick to Laravels conventions this way (tables in plural, models in singular).

You can also add a namespace to the Model with the command. For example if you have your models in `app/Models` directory, you'd write `php artisan make:model -m Models/SomeModel` instead.

> After writing all the code, the migrate command will run all my migrations. Do I use this command after I've written migrations for all tables? Will running it again overwrite tables I already have on the DB?

Laravel creates an SQL table specifically for logging which migrations have already run. It will not run the same migration twice, no matter how many times you execute `php artisan migrate`. Unless you roll them back with some command.

If a table already exists, it will just throw an SQL error saying, can't create a table, since it already exists.

Comment: Can you talk a bit about the make:model command you mentioned? My next step would be to create models for the tables I already have and the new ones. Also, thanks for answering!

Comment: I've edited my answer with some additional explanation. I suggest you just try the commands and see for yourself. If you don't run `php artisan migrate`, you can just delete the files created by commands and nothing will change in the database.

Answer (score 0):

1. there's no need to supply the table name, so this question is moot
2. No, you do not need to do this, see 1
3. `migrate` saves the name of each migration file in the `migrations` table and assigns it a `batch` id. Each subsequent `migrate` command will check for the existence of all file names in the table, and if they aren't present, will add it to the current batch before running the migrations defined within said file